# Правильная сортировка с группировкой

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Применяю underscore для сортировки данных, есть массив данных надо отсортировать, но сортировать надо и не по алфавиту и цифра, а по определенному порядку, заданный заранее, сейчас использую такую сортировку

```
sortedData = _.sortBy(sortedData, (item)=>{ return [item.lang, item.channel, item.status];
```

сортирует по языку и потом в пределах этого языка сортирует по каналу, а вот по каналу своя сортирвока, как мне добавить свою реализацию сортировки туда, там всего четыре варианта канала.

Comment: функция sort с вставкой функции сравнения  https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods читать раздел свой порядок сортировки

Comment: это я знаю, но как можно внедрить в мою схему, какой может быть алгоритм

Comment: @JTan  какие значения имеют каналы и какой порядок нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предположим каналы имеют название a,b,c,d нужный порядок c,b,a,d 
тогда:

```
sortedData = _.sortBy(sortedData, (item)=>{ return [item.lang, {a : 3, b : 2, c : 1, d : 4}[item.channel], item.status]})
```

Comment: работает, спасибо, но еще одна проблема что когда добавляется пятое шестое значение которое должно сортироваться по алфавиту после этих четырех каналов, они почему то встают вперед этих всех других четырех каналов, как сделать чтобы остальное было по алфавиту после четырех этих каналов